# How to override parent method preserving signature?

Tags: python

```py
class Mammal:
    def __init__(self, age: int, name: str):
        """ This is a mammal"""
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        
class Human(Mammal):
    ??? override Mammal's init preserving its signature:
        super().__init__()
        self.job = job
```

So when I type `Human(<Tab>` it should expands Mammal's `__init__` signature.

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` sucks because it clobbers all the signature and docstring.

`def __init__(self, age: int, name: str)` still sucks because whenever Mammal's `__init__` signature changes I have to rewrite it.

How can I override the parent's `__init__` while preserving its signature and docstring?

Comment: [Overrides](https://pypi.org/project/overrides/) is a helper package for this that I know of. I haven't used it myself, since it feels very unsatisfactory answer. Personally, I have opted for `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` but is not optimal due to the reasons you stated.